# Sort brackets after alphanumeric characters?

Tags: python

Working in Python 3:

```
a = ['(', 'z', 'a', '1', '{']
a.sort()
a
['(', '1', 'a', 'z', '{']
```

How can I sort the list so that alphanumeric characters come before punctuation characters:

```
a = ['(', 'z', 'a', '1', '{']
a.custom_sort()
a
['1', 'a', 'z', '(', '{']
```

(Actually I don't care about the order of the last two characters.)

This seems surprisingly difficult!

I understand that Python sorts asciibetically, and I'm looking for a human-readable sort. I found [natsort](https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort) but it only seems to deal with numbers.

Comment: Hm, `sorted(a, key=lambda x: (x[0] == '(', x))` does what I want, though isn't very elegant...

Comment: You just need to specify your own key function to use for the sort.  It can be a lambda if it's very simple, but it can be a more general function (which you can also use elsewhere).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a key function for `sort` that returns a tuple to test if a given character is alphanumeric and use the character's lexicographical order as a secondary sorting key:

```
a.sort(key=lambda c: (not c.isalnum(), c))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `key` function to sorted check if the value is in `string.punctuation`:

```
import string
punctuation = set(string.punctuation)
a = sorted(a, key=lambda x: (x in punctuation, x))
print(a)
#['1', 'a', 'z', '(', '{']
```

Comment: May want to save a `set(string.punctuation)` and check `in` this set to reduce time complexity

Comment: @rafaelc from `string` source code `punctuation = r"""!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~"""` so where is the overhead using `x in string.punctuation'

Comment: sets have `O(1)` access, while strings have `O(k)` being `k` the string length. `k` here is small, I''ll give you that, but still is unnecessary overhead ;} Why iterate over the string if you can have the answer in `O(1)`?

Answer (score 1):

This approach explicitly checks if it's in the right sets:

```
import string
import sys

a = ['(', 'z', 'a', '1', '{']

def key(a):
    if a in string.ascii_letters or a in string.digits:
        return ord(a)
    return sys.maxsize

a.sort(key=key)

print(a)
```